# jdk keytool exception while importing my certificate

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keytool

I am following these tutorials.

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

but whenever I try to execute this command

`keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore <your_keystore_filename> -file <your_certificate_filename>`

I gave your_certificate_filename as (absolute path)JAVA_HOME\bin\mycert.csr

I get exception

`keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException:java.io.IOExcepti
on: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 49)`

I have downloaded : Verisign.com trial certificate : http://www.verisign.com/support/verisign-intermediate-ca/Trial_Secure_Server_Root/index.html

then `keytool -import -alias root -keystore <your_keystore_filename>
    -trustcacerts -file <filename_of_the_chain_certificate>`
this is I guess root certificate and this executed without ant errors.
and then tried above cmd for importing my new certificate

*I am running my cmd prompt in admin mode

What is wrong?

Comment: You aren't following those steps at all. You don't import CSRs. You get them signed, and you import the resulting certificate.

Answer (score 2):

.csr stands for Certificate Signing Request.  You need to either provide that to your CA (sounds like verisign), or create a self-signed cert (a root CA cert) and use that to create a signed cert from the .csr.  You'll usually end up with a .cer or a .pem and a private key, possibly bundled in a keystore or pkcs12 or something similar.